# How to determine cut-off frequency using power spectral density?

Tags: fft, filters

I am new to DSP and my question is a very simple one. It is about determining the right cut-off frequency. I calculate the power spectral density using FFT by Welch's algorithm. However I am confused as to what should be the right cut-off frequency.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Can anyone tell me what is the cut-off frequency in this case:

[image]

Comment: Define cut-off frequency. For lowpass filters the cutoff frequency is usually defined as the frequency where the transfer function $H(f)$ is 3 dB below $H(0)$. But what you show here is a signal spectrum. Sidenote: the labels of your y axis seem to be wrong or at least confusing. Shouldn't they be `0`, `-10`, `-20`,...?

Comment: The y-axis is log-scale. I am trying to remove noise from a pressure transducer. I would like to determine the cut-off frequency to create an adequate filter that can smooth the signal.

Comment: To filter out the useful signal, the signal bandwidth has to be known. In the next step a filter is designed that attenuates all frequencies that are not in the signal frequency range. I understand that the y-axis is logarithmic. But it's also in dB. As $x_\mathrm{dB} = 10\log_{10}(x)$ a value of 0.1 corresponds to -10...unless you're plotting the logarithm of a logarithm.